# Swift 2.0 Realm Library not Loaded

Tags: swift, runtime-error, realm

I recently updated to Swift 2.0 and along with that I needed to update my Realm libraries.  The libraries were previously installed manually, but to update Realm I used cocoa pods.  Everything works great in the simulator, but when I run on my device it get an error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9F8XXSE5-A233-4438-A83E-9D547FE72D2F/MyApp.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
Reason: image not found
```

I have seen other posts where people have raised similar issues but nothing worked/applies to my situation.  (I already have the Realm Swift 1.2 framework in my project, But I am trying to use the 2.0 framework from cocoa pods)

Thank you!

Comment: Sweet!  I fixed the issue doing something similar to that :)  Thanks!

Comment: My fix was to add RealmSwift.framework to Embedded Binaries (it also appears in Linked Frameworks and Libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing the run script command in the build phases.

Specifically:
bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"

Now it runs on the simulator and the device.

Comment: That's indeed only needed for manual installation. CocoaPods "Embed Frameworks" build phase executes a provided script, which takes care of that for all built dependencies.